# "It's almost time to restart" message. How can I see what update it's trying to install?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

I use Windows 10 Pro and I got a "It's almost time to restart" message. How can I see what update it's trying to install?

[image]

Note that Windows automatic updates are supposed to be disabled:

[image]

I looked at the update history but saw nothing recent.

Notes: I'm not connected to an AD domain.

Here is my update history:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you connected to an AD domain? What is shown in “view Update History”?

Comment: @Ramhound update history:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJNqq.png +  https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6R49.png I'm not connected to an AD domain.

Comment: If I were to guess it’s the current cumulative update since your 5 months behind. Windows Update logs would confirm

Answer (score 1):

Click on Wait an Hour to allow the screen above to close.

Then go back to Windows Updates and view the updates, either to install or were installed (history) and this will tell you. If the installed updates are still in the list you will see them here.

There is some chance you will have to restart and then for sure the updates installed are now in Update History. That is your record.

The screen shot is Windows 11 but it is the very same for Windows 10

[image: Windows Update History]

Comment: Thanks, I'd prefer to view it before updating. Also, even after updating, it's not in the update history:  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJNqq.png +  https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6R49.png)

Comment: Yes. run can run Updates (but not wait until too late) and the main update screen will show you what will be installed. I have none to install so I cannot prepare that screen, but main Windows Update always shows you what will be installed..  In your screen shot, just expand Quality Updates (you have expanded Drivers) and the updates to be installed will be there.